# Industry analysis - multiple industries

Tags: data-cleaning, logistic-regression, exploratory-factor-analysis

I am trying to run logistic regression on marketing leads and use industry as a predictor of whether the lead converts (1/0).

Often, when I enrich data from websites like crunchbase the associated company for a lead has multiple industry associations.

I am looking for help in finding a method, as well as R script, to separate these values and ultimately and identify the industries that are the best predictors of conversion.

If anyone can offer some guidance here it would be greatly appreciated.

[image: Example of company + industry data I export from Crunchbase]

Comment: What exactly is the issue you are having? Do you simply export the data to a csv file and want to the split the industries within the 'Industry Groups' column?

Comment: I do want to split the industries. I am also stuck on how to actually analyze and model the data when there are multiple industry values for each lead.